# UILocalizedIndexedCollation for Japanese giving different ordering to contacts/music apps

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uilocalizedcollation

UILocalizedIndexedCollation seems to returning a different result on a Japanese iOS device than that seen in the built in Contacts / Music apps.

Note that this *isn't* the usual question about Japanese not displaying at all in the index. I'm getting the Japanese kana section, but the order of the index is incorrect when compared to Contacts etc.

Here's screens - on the left, the desired result shown in the music app with the kana names first - on the right, the result I'm getting:

[image: itunes screenshot]  [image: screenshot of my app]

UILocalizedIndexedCollation doesn't appear to have any obvious way to configure it, so I'm not sure what the expected way to adjust the ordering is, and a lot of Googling isn't revealing any answers (though I'm also not the only person having this problem). Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have noticed that standard Apple's applications (Contacts, Phone, Music) do always put letters in native alphabet at the top, above Latin letters. In my app I find range of Latin characters in an array returned by sectionIndexTitles method and move them to the end of array. This method also requires a bunch of manipulation with indexes when user taps on the index bar and table view' delegate needs to return correct section index.

Comment: You listen to All Saints?  Well, neither do I.. and I still have this problem.

Comment: I am seeing a similar thing with Arabic locales.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you look at the Table in the Music App it shows the latin "A" character up the top anyway. I suppose Apple modified the Array of the Sidebar to show the current language on top of the other one, even though they still are down the bottom.

Regardless, it's probably easier to just leave it the way it is. You'd have to edit section selection code and all.