# UILocalizedIndexedCollation doesn't work for non-english / chinese indexes

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uilocalizedcollation

I created a table view with sections using the UILocalizedIndexedCollation (supports english, chinese characters in app). This is working perfectly in iOS6. Now in iOS7 and iOS7.1, this feature is not working.

Behaviour:

- Index created is different for iOS6 and iOS7. In iOS7, the chinese index starts with numbers (1-4-8-followed by A-C-K), wherease in iOS6, it starts with (A-C-K followed by 1-4-8).
- Finally, the clicking of section index doesn't take it to the right section.
  It works only in English for iOS7 not for chinese (in iOS6 it works for both).

Expected: It should point to the right section based on the index selected or to the next nearest index.

Any fixes to this or alternate fixes for the same ?.

Relevant Link: [UILocalizedIndexedCollation locale different than English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16832164/uilocalizedindexedcollation-locale-different-than-english)